# Redirect if url missing Google Analytics parameters

Tags: php, url, google-analytics, url-parameters

For a landing page campaign we're pulling in some variables from the url. I need a way to check and see if the 'utm_source=' is present in the url and if it is not redirect the user. We only want traffic from our banner ads, which all have Google Analtyics Links (incl. utm_source).

For example the url "http://www.example.com?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=AdWords&utm_term=Foo&utm_campaign=MyCampaign should work but the url "http://www.example.com" should get redirected to another page

```
<?php
     if (isset($_REQUEST['utm_source'])) {
    // param was set in the query string
    echo('present');
        if(empty($_REQUEST['utm_source'])) {
        // query string had param set to nothing ie ?param=&param2=something
        echo('missing');
        }
    }
 ?>
```

seems right but isn't working correctly. Is there a better way? thank you.

Comment: You should have created unique urls just to use for these campaigns, so you wouldn't need redirects based in GA parameters.

Comment: I have unique url's. if someone strips off the parameters, I don't want that traffic.

Comment: Why would someone get the url from you banner and strip the parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing the closing brace from the first if statement.  That's the culprit.

You want:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['utm_source']) && (!empty($_REQUEST['utm_source']))) {
    // param was set in the query string
    echo('present');
} else {
    // query string had param set to nothing ie ?param=&param2=something
    echo('missing');
}
```

Comment: Have the damdest time c&p code into here sometims. In my code I have it, and if I enter the url w/no parameters, nothing is echo'd. If I enter url w/utm_source= (blank) it echo's both 'presentmissing'

Comment: Why don't you just use an "else", instead of 2 "if"s?

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign : that's the expected behavior.  `isset` checks if the key `utm_source` is present.  It does not check for a value.

Comment: Great, how would I check to make sure the value isn't empty? if ($_REQUEST['utm_source'] !="")

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign : did you check the code I posted in my answer?